# How do I show that the probability of the union of events is not larger than the sum of the individual probabilities?

Tags: probability-theory

In numeric analysis class, we are supposed to show that
$$P\Bigl(\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}A_n\Bigr)\le\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}P(A_n).$$

This is easy to show using induction for a union of finitely many $A_n$, but I'm not sure how to prove this for the required union of countably infinite $A_n$. Indeed, it seems that the statement is questionable as the right hand side may not be finite. Can anybody help me out with the proof?

Comment: Let $B_n=A_n\setminus\left(\bigcup_{i\lt n} A_i\right)$.

Comment: I might be wrong, but isn't this [just the definition of a probability measure](http://www.randomservices.org/random/prob/Probability.html)?

Comment: @NobleMushtak Not quite, we are supposed to show an inequality and the $A_n$ are not necessarily disjoint.

Comment: In the definition, the events are pairwise disjoint, which is not necessarily the case here. Hence the inequality in place of the equality.

Comment: Oh...OK. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the definition of a (probability) measure, you know that

$$P\left(\bigcup_{_{n\in\mathbb{N}}}E_n\right) = \sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}P(E_n)\qquad (1)$$

if the $E_i$ are pairwise dijoint ($E_i\cap E_j =\emptyset,\ i\neq j$). Now, define

$$E_1 = A_1,\ E_2 = A_2\backslash A_1,\ E_3=A_3\backslash (A_1\cup A_2), .. $$

or, more formally,

$$ E_n = A_n\backslash \left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{n-1}A_i\right).$$

The resulting sequence is pairwise disjoint. Therefore, you can apply $(1)$:

$$P\left(\bigcup_{_{n\in\mathbb{N}}}A_n\right)=P\left(\bigcup_{_{n\in\mathbb{N}}}E_n\right) = \sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}P(E_n) \leq \sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}P(A_n)$$

The last inequality uses the monotonicity of the measure. That is

$$P(B)\leq P(C),\ \text{ if } B\subseteq C.$$

Comment: That's a really good idea. Thank you!